# Android after clicking on AdMob ad back button not returning to right Acitvity

Tags: android

I have an application with "Main menu" Activity. From there user can go to Activity1 or Activity2. In Activity1 in have AdMob ads loaded programmaticaly, in Activity2 they are loaded automaticaly from xml file. Problem is that after clicking on ad and loading it in Activity1 when I click back button I get returned back to Main menu instead of Activity1. In Activity2 returning back works like it supposed to. Why is that? Code in Activity1 that is relevant to ads:

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener, AdListener{
    AdView ads;

    public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {}
    public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad, AdRequest.ErrorCode error){}

    public void onPresentScreen(Ad ad){}
    public void onDismissScreen(Ad ad){}
    public void onLeaveApplication(Ad ad){}
    ...

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        ads.setAdListener(this);
        ads.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        ads = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        ads.setAdListener(this);
        ads.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "clicking on ad and _loading it in Activity1_"? Do you override the `AdView`'s `onClick`?

Comment: If I click on ad shown in Activity1 it loads normaly but when I press back button it returns me to Main menu. I have just make 
ads.setAdListener(this);ads.loadAd(new AdRequest());

Comment: I've also added public void onPresentScreen(Ad ad){},
 public void onDismissScreen(Ad ad){} and 
 public void onLeaveApplication(Ad ad){}

Comment: Can you please post the section of your code that is relevant to the AdMob?

Comment: I know what was wrong. I overrid onStop() method and put finish(); in it